# How can I add an element in object at certain position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this object:

```
var ages = [{
  "getasafieldDetail": {
    "id": "xxx",
    "asaentrySet": [{
      "result": "ON",
      "buy": {
        "username": "Dis"
      },
      "offerSet": [{
        "createdStr": "2001-08-09 at 11:52 pm",
        "value": 5.0
      }]
    }]
  }
}];
```

and i want to add an element and have an output like this:

```
var ages = [{
  "getasafieldDetail": {
    "id": "xxx",
    "asaentrySet": [{
      "result": "ON",
      "buy": {
        "username": "Dis"
      },
      "land": "111", // THIS <<<<------------
      "offerSet": [{
        "createdStr": "2001-08-09 at 11:52 pm",
        "value": 5.0
      }]
    }]
  }
}];
```

i tried using `splice` but not works...

```
ages.splice(ages[0]['getasafieldDetail']['asaentrySet'][0]['offerSet'],0,'"land": "111"');
ages.join();
```

Comment: @depperm i don't understand your comment...

Comment: Objects have _properties_. Arrays have elements. :)

Comment: You should explain why you need this. It's anti-pattern and I suspect an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Borja ... From all the provided answers are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the handy syntax of [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which helps with cutting and reassembling objects.

***Edit***

*@FireFuro99* did point to the ES6/ES2015 spec which explicitly states how to preserve/handle an object's key-order at the object's creation time.

Thus one can say ...

> Every JS engine which does support *Destructuring assignment* has to respect too any object's key order from/at this object's creation time.

```js
const ages = [{
  getasafieldDetail: {
    id: "xxx",
    asaentrySet: [{
      result: "ON",
      buy: {
        username: "Dis",
      },
      offerSet: [{
        createdStr: "2001-08-09 at 11:52 pm",
        value: 5.0,
      }],
    }],
  },
}];

const { result, buy, ...rest } = ages[0].getasafieldDetail.asaentrySet[0];

ages[0].getasafieldDetail.asaentrySet[0] = {
  result,
  buy,
  land: "111",
  ...rest,
};

console.log({ ages });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Afaik ES2015 guarantees that String keys are always iterated in insertion order, and that the insertion order is preserved.

Comment: @FireFuro99 ... You are right about the spec. Thus on could say. Every JS engine which does support  *Destructuring assignment* also has to respect the key order at/of any object's creation time.

Answer (score 1):

Splice only works on Arrays.

To make this work, convert your Object to an Array using `Object.entries()`, then use splice, and then convert it back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

```
const entrySet = Object.entries(ages[0]['getasafieldDetail']['asaentrySet'][0]);
entrySet.splice(2,0, ["land", "111"]);
ages[0]['getasafieldDetail']['asaentrySet'][0] = Object.fromEntries(entrySet);
```

This will insert the key-value pair at the the specified position.

The advantage this has over the destructuring assignment is, that you can specify the index, whereas destructuring is pretty hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

`ages[0]["getasafieldDetail"]["asaentrySet"][0].land = '111'` will create the key `land` in the first object in `asaentrySet` and assign the value `111`. Key order is not guaranteed

```js
var ages = [{
  "getasafieldDetail": {
    "id": "xxx",
    "asaentrySet": [{
      "result": "ON",
      "buy": {
        "username": "Dis"
      },
      "offerSet": [{
        "createdStr": "2001-08-09 at 11:52 pm",
        "value": 5.0
      }]
    }]
  }
}];

ages[0]["getasafieldDetail"]["asaentrySet"][0].land = '111'

console.log(ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it is an array of objects you could simple, add, passing the position that you want by editing the array like the example below:

```
let land = {land: 1111}
let ages = [{'a':11},'2', 'wd']
let new =[] 
new.push(ages[1])
new.push(land)
ages[1] = new
console.log(ages)
```

output:

```
(3) [{…}, Array(2), "wd"]
```

You get what you want from the array, edit it, and put back in the same position, may it can help.